# SQL Server 2008 Expr. SP2 install fails - "failed to retrieve data for this request.."

Tags: sql-server-2008

I tried to install SQL Server 2008 Express SP2 but the installation process fails with the following error message "failed to retrieve data for this request.."
First the window "SQL server installation center" appears. If click on "new installation" then the error message comes up.

What can i do to completely remove SQL server from my system to do a clean new install of SQLS2008R2?

Other question. I found this folder in my user folder:

[image]

[image: content of MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS]

Any idea why this folder is located under "user"?
Can i delete this folder?

Can i delete SQL Server by deleting all registry keys and deleting
all the files in the folder "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server"?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Greatly appreciated.

-Sammy

Comment: So you are saying that moment you click on new installation it failed. Or you configured installation by selecting various options but during installation it failed ? You can delete MSSQLEXPRESS folder. Can you find relevant logs at [this location](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143702%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for anwering.
Yes.
I click "new installation" then it fails.
Hmm, how to add additional screen shots?

Comment: Yes.
I click "new installation" then it fails.
In the LOG folder i found this file (Summary.txt): [link](http://www.rebel66.de/ForumPosts/Summary.txt)

Comment: Here 3 screenshots:
1) [link](http://www.rebel66.de/ForumPosts/Setup-1.png)
2) [link](http://www.rebel66.de/ForumPosts/Setup-2.png)
3) [link](http://www.rebel66.de/ForumPosts/Setup-3.png)

Comment: I cannot understand the screenshots they are not in English. Can translate the message in English

Comment: Ok. Have commented the screenshots and also the log file "Summary.txt".
Summary.txt reports: "Trial to process a not authorised operation."

Comment: Here`s the updated log file: In the LOG folder i found this file (Summary.txt): [link] (http://www.rebel66.de/ForumPosts/Summary1.txt)